# How can multiple rows can be concatenated into one column in php

Tags: php, database

**Data:**

```
id   name  year  Date
1    raj   2013  12-10-2013
1    raj   2014  10-09-2014
1    raj   2016  02-03-2016
1    raj   2015  10-09-2015
```

**Desired result:**

```
id   name                       year     
              2013         2014         2015       2016
1    raj     12-10-2013  10-09-2014   10-09-2015  02-03-2016
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Very poorly redacted question. You didn't even format the data.

Comment: please make format. i didnt understand what you asked/

Comment: yes,id and name should be same.i want to format multiple rows into single column

Answer (score 0):

try this as a simple solution (of course the new array could also be dynamically generated so the array_values is not needed)
You also don't mention if you have the data as an array or directly from the database. If it doesn't harm that the $newData array is indexed by the id instead of an zero index you also don't need the array_values call.

I also guess that the `name` is the same for a specific `id`.

```
$newData = array();
if (is_array($data)) {
    foreach ($data as $row) {
      $id= $row['id'];
      $name= $row['name'];
      $year= $row['year'];
      $date= $row['date'];

      $newData[$id][$id] = $id;
      $newData[$id][$name] = $name;
      $newData[$id][$year] = $date;
    }
    $newData = array_values($newData);
}
```